# C# Output Assembly Filename (csproj)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, csproj

Is there any way to change the output assembly filename when building by VS?

I have two (four, including Debug/Release branches) configurations with a bit different functionality and that should be used differently, but should remain in same dir. So, the best are ProjectName.dll and ProjectName.Test.dll.

Please, don't advice to change AssemblyName parameter (the only hint I saw by googling the SO), they are not the same. AssemblyName also changes the full classname for every class and this is not desired. I want to change *only* the filename and remain anything inside assembly unthouched.

Now I've done this by adding AfterBuild target into .csproj that copies assemblies with rename, but i don't like this solution. May it be easier?

Also tried to set OutputPath to SomeWhere\ProjectName.Test.dll - it simply creates dir ProjectName.Test.dll and places $(AssemblyName).dll there.

UPD: Clearer explanation, why the AssemblyName change is not what I want. AssemblyName is also the part of every type in assembly (it points to the assembly, from where is type is) and it directly applies to type resolve.
For example, I reference ProgName.dll for ISome interface. The resolver tries to find ProgName (as set in type's metadata) and founds nothing, because there is no ProgName, only ProgName.Test. When they all have AssemblyName ProgName (not .Test), it will work. Of course, if I deal with different filenames.

UPD2: Even better explanation of what I meant when said about the AssemblyName:
[image: Resolver data screenshot]
The red-marked is what assembly resolver tries to find. Assembly in both of my configurations have the same interface, so the client should not care about what assembly he need to find. Both should have the same AssemblyName, but different filename (to be stored in same folder).

I've used ILRepack to merge several assemblies into one:

- A.dll
- B.dll (or B.Test.dll, depending on configuration)
- C.dll

Both A and C reference B.dll. If I merge B.Test.dll instead (with AssemblyName "B.Test") the references will remain references. If I merge B.dll, no references remain (all code inside). So I need B.Test.dll (with this filename) to have AssemblyName "B".

Comment: Can you explain about "changing AssemblyName changes the full classname"? If I change assembly name either through VS (Project > <project> properties > Application > Assembly name) or through manually changing csproj (AssemblyName property), my existing namespaces and class names remain the same. Also the "Default namespace" property doesn't change (RootNamespace in csproj). Do you maybe have some extension installed that syncs your root namespaces when assembly name is changed?

Comment: If renaming is all that is required then what exactly do you not like about using a post-build script?

Comment: Luc, [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) Full typename includes the AssemblyName and the same is used to resolve the assembly for type (the assembly from where the given type). Changing the AssemblyName causes different type resolve problems for me, I can fix them, but it is better to avoid.

Comment: blins, Why I should rename, when it might be possible to build with right filename?:) Unelegant.

Comment: I think what @Luc meant - and what I'd advise you to do, too - is to change the the `AssemblyName` property in the `csproj`-file. Could it simply be an misunderstanding and you're talking at cross-purposes?

Comment: khlr, please, read question carefully. I said, that changing the AssemblyName is not answer. And said why. Can you advice something else? Repeat: I don't want to change the assembly identity itself. I want to change only the filename, where the csc writes file during build.

Comment: OK, with your updated question it is quite clear what you want. Unfortunately I don't see any other (immediate) way than copying/renaming the created dll. That being said, there's a tonne of hooks in the MSBuild process. There might be one that "calculates" the assembly filename as well as its identity. If you want to go down this road, the MSBuild parameter "/pp[:filepath]" is your friend. This outputs your csproj with every import inlined which you can analyze. And word to the wise, don't use this generated file for debugging/building (I've spent too much time on this VS bug already).

Comment: Hans, tried. Not works, I've explained the result in question post.

Answer (score 8):

Just to illustrate what Luc already mentioned in his comment: You could easily tweak some lines in your `csproj`-file and achieve what you're looking for.

Please take a look at this sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <someProps>....</someProps>
    <RootNamespace>Your.Project</RootNamespace> <!-- Your project namespace stays the same -->
    <AssemblyName>Your.Project</AssemblyName>
    <someMoreProps>...</someMoreProps>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AssemblyName>Your.Project.Foo</AssemblyName> <!-- you could simply "override" the resulting assembly name -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <samePropsAsAbove>...</samePropsAsAbove>
    <AssemblyName>Your.Project.Bar</AssemblyName> <!-- you could do this on a per-configuration-basis -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

By doing so you're simply changing the resulting output file. So in this example the output (using debug configuration) would be `Your.Project.Foo.dll` instead of the default `Your.Project.dll`.

This doesn't change any class name or the namespaces which you're assuming.

Comment: Now the misunderstanding takes place. I never assume class name or ns change when I change AssemblyName. I mean the class metadata. When we try to create the instance of

Comment: oops. ...when we try to create the instance of the class from our "renamed" assembly, what dll the assembly resolver will search for?

Comment: Could you please update your question once again and post a snippet of how you're using the resolver? I think this would help to help you :)